# VBA Macro runs fine in my PC but gives me overflow error in Excel with work laptop

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, concatenation

Overflow error on the debugger is highlighting this line:

```
concatenatedValue = IIf(isDateColumn, Format(currentData, "mm/dd/yyyy"), currentData)
```

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ConcatenateRowsByUniqueID()
    Dim uniqueIDColumn As Range
    Dim dataColumn As Range
    Dim isDateColumn As Boolean
    Dim resultColumn As Range
    Dim uniqueIDDict As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    
    ' Prompt for user input
    On Error Resume Next
    Set uniqueIDColumn = Application.InputBox("Select the column with unique IDs", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set dataColumn = Application.InputBox("Select the column with data to concatenate", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If uniqueIDColumn Is Nothing Or dataColumn Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Invalid selection. Please try again.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    isDateColumn = MsgBox("Is the selected data column a date?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes
    
    ' Set the result column
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set resultColumn = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1)
    
    ' Initialize a dictionary to store unique IDs and their concatenated results
    Set uniqueIDDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    ' Loop through the data and concatenate values
    For i = 1 To uniqueIDColumn.Rows.Count
        Dim currentID As Variant
        Dim currentData As Variant
        Dim concatenatedValue As String
        
        currentID = uniqueIDColumn.Cells(i, 1).Value
        currentData = dataColumn.Cells(i, 1).Value
        
        If Not IsEmpty(currentID) Then
            ' Check if the ID is already in the dictionary
            If uniqueIDDict.Exists(currentID) Then
                ' Concatenate the data to the existing value
                concatenatedValue = uniqueIDDict(currentID) & "," & IIf(isDateColumn, Format(currentData, "mm/dd/yyyy"), currentData)
            Else
                ' Add the ID to the dictionary
                concatenatedValue = IIf(isDateColumn, Format(currentData, "mm/dd/yyyy"), currentData)
            End If
            
            ' Store the concatenated result in the dictionary
            uniqueIDDict(currentID) = concatenatedValue
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Output the results to the worksheet
    For i = 1 To uniqueIDColumn.Rows.Count
        Dim outputID As Variant
        outputID = uniqueIDColumn.Cells(i, 1).Value
        
        If Not IsEmpty(outputID) Then
            ' Retrieve the concatenated result from the dictionary and output to the result column
            ws.Cells(i, resultColumn.Column).Value = uniqueIDDict(outputID)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

The result is supposed to join cells from the same column but different rows into one cell using the unique ID from another column. The result has to repeat where the unique ID row is. For example:

```
Unique ID| Data   | Result
098765   | AB.123 | AB.123 
654312   | CD.345 | CD.345,GH.098
654312   | GH.098 | CD.345,GH.098
340076   | EF.678 | EF.678
```

Comment: What are the values of `isDateColumn` and `currentData` when the error occurs?

Comment: Just post the values - imgur is blocked by many corporates so you are limiting the number of people who can help you

Comment: What version of Excel is the works laptop ?

Comment: The output is too long for text which is why I posted the image.
@BigBen I just ran it a couple of times and it worked? No idea why it would sometimes give me an overflow error though. Either way, here's the output in text form: 


`False
AB.980879JQEE
False
AB.980875VEU2
False
AB.98087CZB25
False
AB.98087MEC8L
False
AB.98087JZEVZ
False
AB.98087W46HW
False
AB.98087X3A6R
False
AB.980872FS62
False
AB.98087VGNNM
False
AB.98087PFAF0
False
AB.9808799KMO
False
AB.98087I0A5U
False
AB.98087IJXHK
False
AB.98087U1GPG
False
AB.980877Q54O
False
AB.98087BNDGY`

Comment: @CDP1802: Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2308 Build 16.0.16731.20310) 64-bit

Comment: Are you selecting entire column with InputBox or just relevant rows ?

Comment: I'm choosing the entire column

Comment: That means `uniqueIDColumn.Rows.Count` in the For loop would be 1,048,576. You could reduce it with `Set uniqueIDColumn = Intersect(uniqueIDColumn, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)` and same for `dataColumn`. Put after `Set resultColumn ...`
`